# How to use case to construct a conditional update

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to write an update query. If the `special_member` account is not cancelled then in the `where` clause I have to use this condition by adding a grace period of 15 days to the expiry date and compare it today's date:

```
Convert(date,MEMBER_EXPIRY_DATE + 15) >= Convert(date,GETDATE())
```

If the membership is cancelled then I have to compare the actual expiry date with today's date. This is my full query:

```
UPDATE SPECIAL_MEMBER SET SAVINGS_PERCENT = 10, ORDER_COUNT = 1 
WHERE SPECIAL_MEMBER = '4382' AND CASE WHEN (CANCELLED = 0) THEN  
Convert(date,MEMBER_EXPIRY_DATE + 15) >= Convert(date,GETDATE())
ELSE  (Convert(date,MEMBER_EXPIRY_DATE) >= Convert(date,GETDATE())) END
```

When I execute it I am getting:

> Incorrect syntax near '>'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a `case` *expression*, not a *statement*, as as such it can only return a value i.e. cannot contain any conditions. Just move the value you are comparing to outside the `case` e.g.

```
UPDATE SPECIAL_MEMBER SET
    SAVINGS_PERCENT = 10
    , ORDER_COUNT = 1 
WHERE SPECIAL_MEMBER = '4382'
AND CASE WHEN CANCELLED = 0
    THEN CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(DAY,15,MEMBER_EXPIRY_DATE)) 
    ELSE CONVERT(DATE,MEMBER_EXPIRY_DATE) END >= CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE());
```

That however is not sargable i.e. cannot make use of any indexes on `MEMBER_EXPIRY_DATE` so I would recommend switching the logic around to

```
UPDATE SPECIAL_MEMBER SET
    SAVINGS_PERCENT = 10
    , ORDER_COUNT = 1 
WHERE SPECIAL_MEMBER = '4382'
AND MEMBER_EXPIRY_DATE >= CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(DAY,CASE WHEN CANCELLED = 0 THEN -15 ELSE 0 END,GETDATE()))
```

Notes:

- Dates don't naturally add, use the `dateadd` function.
- There is nothing dynamic about this - dynamic SQL is something quite different
- Using a good layout and consistent casing makes a big difference in being able to read your SQL

Comment: @Kim see my performance improvement (you'll need to double check the logic).

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the CASE and use like below:

```
UPDATE SPECIAL_MEMBER 
    SET SAVINGS_PERCENT = 10
      , ORDER_COUNT = 1 
    WHERE SPECIAL_MEMBER = '4382' 
      AND ( CANCELLED = 0 AND DATEADD(dd,15,CONVERT(DATE, MEMBER_EXPIRY_DATE)) >= CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())
            OR CANCELLED != 0 AND CONVERT(DATE,MEMBER_EXPIRY_DATE) >= CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()))
```